# When you need to tell airport employees where you want to go, do they prefer it if you use the IATA code or the ICAO code?

Tags: airport-operations

(This is a question by a civilian, but please know that I do understand the system behind the IATA codes and the ICAO codes)

I want to know, when I go to an airport to fly somewhere and want to use airport codes instead of airport names, if the airport employees prefer you to tell them the IATA code or the ICAO code to inform them of the location where you want to go

Comment: Not an airport employee so just a comment, but I would suggest IATA every time. It's what the airlines themselves use, after all. (Hence the name.)

Comment: What 4-letter code do you use if you want to tell an airport employee where you'd like *them* to go?  ;)

Comment: ENVA is located right next door to [Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell,_Norway) after all...

Answer (score 1):

IATA codes. That's what the airlines use, and what will be on your ticket and baggage tags.

The name of the airport is also acceptable, of course.